# Visual studio - stand alone application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dll

Hello I have created a DLL file using visual C++ 2010, that runs a C script that i have written.
I have then created a user interface using visual C# 2010 and linked everything together.

On my machine the resulting exe application runs perfectly.
However when i try to put the folder, containing BOTH the exe and the dll, on other computers.. it runs on some computers, but on others it does not.

the error i receive has to do with "Cant find dll file or assembly".

All computers have windows  7 64bit installed.

My question is: Is there a requirement for the application to run? (files or something that should be installed on all machines???)

I have noticed the following (after alot of looking) that:
the computers that run the application HAVE visual studio 2010 installed
the computers that do not run the application DO NOT have visual studio 2010 but have visual studio 2008 installed..
all computers have .NET framework 4.5 installed.

Do you think the visual studio has anything to do with this?!!? isnt the point having a stand alone application is to make the app run on any machine?
Is there a way to fix it so that the app will run on any computer regarding having visual installed or not?

thank you all..

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)** to check what dll the program can't find.

Just load the .exe into the program.

Answer (score 0):

You might also find that you will need to install the [Visual Studio 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632) on those computers that you are deploying to.